# For a SSIS project how do I construct a Script Component to handle OAuth 2.0O access?

Tags: c#, api, oauth-2.0, ssis

I am building an SSIS project in Visual Studio to access an API server that uses OAuth2 to move data to our Azure SQL Server. Instead of using third party options, I have to create a script component to reach out to the API server with OAuth2. The script component will be using C# code. Any suggestions or advice would be a big help.

Unable to local any resources regarding Auth 2.0 authorization and SSIS script component.